# Input Button as SUBMIT

Tags: forms, button, input, submit, enter

I need to have a form submitted using the enter key, however, I have to use a BUTTON instead of SUBMIT as the type in order for the page to not refresh. How can I get my BUTTON to act as a SUBMIT and be executed whenever someone pushes their enter key?

```
<form>
<input type=text ...>
<input type=button ...>
</form>
```

A lot of the information I found about this mentions Netscape/IE/lots of outdated material.

This is my HTML output, I'm looking to hide the submit button and use ENTER:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ohepe.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have to use a BUTTON instead of SUBMIT as the type in order for the page to not refresh

Nah. Use a normal `submit` button that refreshes the page. (And ideally, for accessibility, make it work!) Then add progressive enhancement to replace the submission action of the form with something smoother when JS is available. Use `return false` (or `event.preventDefault()` in the DOM 2 Events model) to stop the form submitting in this case.

```
<form id="foo" method="POST" action="dosomething.script">
    ...
    <input type="submit" value="Do something"/>
</form>

document.getElement('foo').onsubmit= function() {
    beginAJAXSubmission();
    return false;
};
```

Catching the `submit` event of a form is generally better than trying to pick up `click` on buttons, because it will always fire when the form would normally be submitted, including on Enter keypresses. `click` on the first submit button in a form will *usually* be fired on an Enter keypress, but there are cases (depending on number of controls in the form and what browser it is) where it doesn't happen and so you can end up falling through to actually submitting the form.

Comment: I HAVE to have it NOT refresh as it's a means of using it as a chatroom.

Comment: returning false will stop it from refreshing or if you pass `e` as the param you can use `e.preventDefault()` to stop it as well.

Comment: @Jessica: we can't really see much from a screenshot of the rendered HTML, but, again, I can assure you that a form whose `submit` event you respond to with `return false`/`preventDefault` will NOT cause the page to be reloaded.

Comment: @bobince Can I e-mail you my code? It would really help to have someone look at it.

Comment: If you need to, please post it here. SO is here to help people learn from each other, which doesn't happen in private e-mail.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){
 var refreshchat = function(){
  $.get('ajax.php', function(data) {
   $('#messages').html(data);
  });
  var msgs = document.getElementById('messages');
  msgs.scrollTop = msgs.scrollHeight;
 }
 var getmsgs = self.setInterval(refreshchat,0);
 $('#send').click(function(){
  var msg = $('#msg').val();
  $.post("ajax.php", { msg: msg, from: "You" },
     function(data) {
    $('#messages').html(data);
    $('#msg').val('');
    var msgs = document.getElementById('messages');
    msgs.scrollTop = msgs.scrollHeight;
  });
 });
});`

Comment: Form: `<form>
        <input type="text" id="msg" />
        <input type="button" id="send" value="Send" /> 
      </form>`

Comment: And this this on top: `<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])){
 $_SESSION['id'] = rand(0,100);
}
?>`

Comment: Give the `<form id="chat">` or some other way to identify it, then change the button to `type="submit"` and replace `$('#send').click(` to `$('#chat').submit(`. Finally, add `return false;` to the end of that `submit` function, just before the final `});`. That's really all!

Comment: Okay, now, how do I make the page NOT refresh when I submit?

Comment: Again, the `return false;` statement in an event handler function will stop the default action of the event. Stopping the form submitting means no page reload. I assume that is what you are talking about. If you want to stop the chat window updating when you send something, simply omit the `.html(data)` call.

Comment: I want it to update still, but not refresh the page when I submit.

Answer (score 3):

with Javascript enabled

```
<input type="button" onclick="this.form.submit()" ... />
```

should work

Comment: It didn't. See link attached.

Answer (score 1):

as other said, you have to use Javascript.  I recommend JQuery framework.

But i don't understand the refresh thing?

Normal way is you hit submit and your form will be sent over a request to the server.
Server process the data and return a response (HTML/JSon..etc) this response will normally be redirect to a result page (to avoid the famous warning about re-post on refresh).

Now if your form is only a little piece of a bigger page, you might want to use ajax to post the little form and then take the result and update your DOM.

All this said, nothing prevent you to use submit type for the button, it is actually the best way to make your enter key defaut to this action.  All you have to do is to use Jquery and intercept the submit of your form and make an ajax call instead of going the normal way.

you will find plenty of example to use JQuery since its probably the most used javascript framework.

Hope it help